# Why is the type of 'base' object my concrete type?

Tags: c#, gethashcode

It seems a very simple question, but clearly I'm missing something.
I did a test:

```
class A
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(base.GetType().Name);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I was expecting to find 'object' but I find 'A'. 
I was relying on this behaviour to invoke the base `GetHashCode` is particular cases withing an implementation, calling `base.GetHashCode()` and I was expecting the `object` implementation to be invoked.

What's wrong?

Comment: The `object` implementation of `GetType()` is designed to return real runtime object type and that is what it is doing here.

Comment: `GetType()` will always return the concrete, actual subclass of the instance it's invoked on. `base.GetHashCode()`, in this case, should invoke the `Object.GetHashCode()` method. EDIT: So, I'm not entirely sure what the problem is you're facing, or why it's not invoking the `object` implementation of the method. Perhaps you need to show the actual code you're using or better clarify your question.

Comment: Note that `Object.GetType()` is *not* a virtual method. Invoking it through `base` will do nothing special (unlike `base.GetHashCode()`, which will). If you want to get your base type at runtime, use `this.GetType().BaseType`. (This need not be the compile-time type your class is deriving from, if invoked from deeper in the inheritance hierarchy.)

Comment: you simply want `new object().GetType().Name` or `typeof(object).Name`

Comment: @JeroenMostert The fact that it’s virtual or not is irrelevant. `base.GetType()` will return something different if the type hides `object.GetType()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`base.` notation changes method that is called for overridden `virtual` methods (like `GetHashCode` in your sample - `base.GetHashCode()` calls `object.GetHashCode`, `this.GetHashCode()` calls `A.GetHashCode()`). `base.` can also be used to hidden base class' method, but it is not the case in this sample.

Since `GetType` is not virtual and there is no hiding then calling `this.GetType()` and `base.GetType()` behaves identical and calls `object.GetType` which returns "The exact runtime type of the current instance" as specified in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: If `GetType` is hidden will both still return the same?

Comment: @InBetween yes, you are right - you can use `base` to call hidden one. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

`GetType()` always returns the current type, even if called on `base`. To get the base type, you can do this:

```
class A
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().BaseType.Name);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

BTW `base.GetHashCode()` works as expected. If you call it within `A` it will execute the `object` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing two very different things here. One is *what* method implementation is called and the other is what the *runtime type* type of the object is.

`object.GetType()` is implemented in `object` and it will always return the *runtime type* of the instance it’s called upon.

Now, when you call method `Foo` from any given class that doesn’t implement `Foo` but rather inherits it from a base type (your case), `base.Foo` or `Foo` are essentially the same thing because the only existing `Foo` is `base.Foo`.

However, if the class implements it’s own `Foo`, bet it overriding a virtual method *or hiding a non virtual method* the method called will be different. Don’t get confused by the other answers stating that the behavior you are seeing is due to `GetType` not being virtual, that is not true.

```
class A { int Foo() => 1;}
class B { }
class C { new int Foo() => 2; }
```

Calling `Foo` or `base.Foo` from within `B` is the same, calling it from within `C` is not; the former will return `2` the latter `1`.

Answer (score -1):

Equalsk's comment and post ([here for brevity](http://%20learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/)) are what you need to know, but I'll go an extra step and tell you why you want it this way.

Given `class A` only inherits from `System.Object`,
And given `class B` and `class C` are subclasses of `class A`:

In class B or C, the `base.GetType().Name` will be A.  You expected this because it's defined in the subclasses that they inherit from A.

In class A, you still get A.  Why wouldn't you want `object`?

The answer is simple.   Say I write a method like this one:

```
public static void DoStuff(A input)
{
}
```

I can send `DoStuff(input)` with `input` being classes A, B, or C.  This is because their `base` type is A.   This is desirable.   We wouldn't want to implicitly (and confusingly) exclude class A from a method that takes its derivatives; if we did, we'd want A to be an uninstantiable interface.

Think of `System.Object` as an ancestor.   If someone asks you where you came from, you don't respond "Evolution in Mesopotamia", you typically would just address the lineage relevant to your existence. The `object` class is essentially primordial ooze, so you won't reference it unless you're trying to tell something it should accept anything it's passed as a parameter, or are unsure what object type you'll deal with.

An example of that last case is this:

```
public void DoStuffAgain(object x)
{
        Messagebox.Show(x.GetType().Name);
}
```

In theory, everything coming down the pipe would be `object`.   Instead, you might pass this your "A" class, and you'd want to know "A" because that's what you passed it.  This is true even though x is of type `object`.

`BaseType` (a property) will return your base for a class, as stated in other answers. This won't lead you to `object`, though, unless the class doesn't explicitly inherit from something else.